# Comma before "тоже" between two modifiers modifying the same noun

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Do I need a comma after the word **Другая** here?:

> ...эта история и по сей день тревожит их умы. 
>   **Другая**, тоже весьма
>   популярная история в наших кругах – о том, как в деревню приходили
>   медведи – также не даёт им покоя...

Comment: Is it your phrase? Any specific reason you don't use topic-comment order? (*другая история, тоже весьма популярная…*)

Comment: @Quassnoi - It's a transcription of a spoken speech. I am not allowed to change any words or word order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Lopatin's *Полный академический справочник*:

> § 84. Присоединительные члены предложения имеют характер сведений добавочных, сообщаемых попутно, в дополнение к содержанию основного высказывания. Такие члены предложения выделяются запятыми и обычно вводятся словами и сочетаниями слов (частицами, союзами или их сочетанием) *даже, в особенности, особенно, главным 
>   образом, в том числе, в частности, например, и притом, и потому, да и, да и только, да и вообще, и, тоже, и тоже, причем* и др.: …
>
> - Большое, тоже квадратное, окно выходило в садик (Зал.);

You need to isolate the whole clause with commas:

> Другая, тоже весьма популярная, история в наших кругах…

I should mention that the way this sentence is built makes the modifier dangling: *в наших кругах* comments *история* rather than *популярная* which it apparently should.